# Putting a mathemethical formula into java

Tags: java

> **Exercise 2.12**
>   (Compute arithmetic progression) An arithmetic progression(AP) or arithmetic sequence is a sequence of numbers such that the difference between the consecutive terms is constant. For instance the sequence 5,7,9,11,13,15... is an AP with a common difference of 2. If the initial term of an AP is A1 and the common difference of successive members is d, then the nth term of the sequence an is given by:
>
> ```
> a n = a 1 + (n-1)*d
> ```
>
> Write a program that prompts the user to enter a 1 and d and computes a 46.
>
> Enter speed and acceleration: 60 3.5
>   The minimum runway length for this airplane is 514.286

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Chapter2Exercise12 {
     public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter speed: ");

    double speed = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter acceleration: ");

    double acceleration = input.nextDouble();

    double length = speed + (46 - 1)* acceleration;


    System.out.println("The minimum runway length for this airplane is " +
    length + " meters");

    }
}
```

This is the answer from the book:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Exercise02_12 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter speed v: ");
        double v = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter acceleration a: ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();

        double length = v * v / (2 * a);

        System.out.println("The minimum runway length for this airplane is " +
        length + " meters");
  }
}
```

Does anyone understand how they get the formula from length?

It can be relevant to other people who don't understand this and need to apply this in a project.

Comment: @Andy Turner  why is it 2 * a? It's been such a long time since I swapped s = and v = and a = :D

Comment: @Tom , Tom I was wondering my post was first downvoted after this it got upvoted why does the system still not allow me to ask questions?

Comment: There are several restrictions from new users which aren't necessarily connected to your vote score. You can find more by search for "new user restrictions", like http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your code is computing A46 term correctly.

But, the question was they were **actually** asking is missing something like that:

"An airplane starts its liftoff in velocity 0. 
Ask the user to type in the airplane's acceleration and liftoff speed (minimal speed needed for liftoff).

Compute the minimal length needed for the runway."

The answer, of course, is by using the formulas previously mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @ Java Guy next door So basically I missunderstood that a1 was the speed but speed = 0 at start. So they ask basically what is the speed before the plane liftoff? correct?

Comment: I think they ask the liftoff speed from the user (60 in the example).